# Sql Query to find out Last Five Reords which created Or updated and before how much time with created and modified Date?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one table name as a_campaign  in MySQL Database that have following columns

```
CampaignId | name | Created Date | Modified Date |
```

Now What I want is to Display Latest 5 Records From the Above table as Recently Created Or Recently updated ...

I don't know How can I fetch this records as per my requirement..so please if anyone can guide me..

My Resulted Data Should be Fetched Like Following

```
Campaign Id | Campaign Name | Status(Updated/Created) | Time (Created/Modified Before)
```

the last column should be shows the times that campaign Created or updated before how many Months/Weeks/days/hours/minutes/seconds comparing with today's date)

Please Help Me Out..

[image]

Comment: can you give sample data with your desired result?

Comment: Could you describe what "Status(Updated/Created)" and "Time (Created/Modified Before)" mean in your desired resultset?

Comment: time like if there is any records which today's date and modified date/created date Diffrence (in minutes /seconds/weeks/days/months)..status means its updated or created Recentely

Answer (score 2):

This should achieve it.  You can adjust the last column to be formatted as you wish, but that gives how many minutes ago the activity occurred

```
SELECT 
    campaignId,
    name,
    CASE WHEN modifieddate > createddate THEN 'Updated' ELSE 'Created' END AS type_of_activity,
    modifieddate AS latest_activity,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,modifieddate,NOW()) AS minutes_ago
FROM
    a_campaign
ORDER BY 
    modifieddate DESC
```

Comment: thanx man its worked like charms///now need only compute the time on depends of minutes

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not quite understanding your desired resultset structure, but to sort by either column, you could do this:

```
select *, greatest(Created, Modified) as lastDate
from a_campaign
order by lastDate desc 
limit 5;
```

Note that this does a full table scan. So you might want to add constraints on both Created and Modified (say either one need to be more recent than 24 hours ago) to limit the size of your resultset (indexes on the date columns would help)

Additionally, to make this simple, I assume Modified is always greater or equal than Created. So you should make your app populate **both** Created and Modified at row creation time, and update only Modified on change. If you do that, you can simplify the query to only sort by the Modified column DESC, and get the top 5.

[Edit] I just saw you added a sample of your dataset, which indicates that both Created and Modified *are* populated at row creation time. In that case, it sounds like you just need a sort on the Modified column:

```
select *
from a_campaign
order by Modified desc 
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

please use this procedure

```
DECLARE @TABLES TABLE(ID INT , Name NVarchar(50),status NVarchar(50), time int,time1 datetime)

INSERT INTO @TABLES
SELECT ID,Name,'Created',DATEDIFF(D,CreatedDate,GETDATE()),CreatedDate FROM Compaign WHERE CreatedDate > ModifiedDate

INSERT INTO @TABLES
SELECT ID,Name,'Updated',DATEDIFF(D,ModifiedDate,GETDATE()),ModifiedDate FROM Compaign WHERE CreatedDate <= ModifiedDate

select ID 'Campaign Id' ,Name 'Campaign Name', status 'Status(Updated/Created)', time 'Time (Created/Modified Before)' from @TABLES order by time1 asc
```